# Entity Framework Core Code First is not working with existing Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm following [this](https://fildev.net/2018/03/30/ef-core-code-first-with-existing-database-asp-net-core/) link to learn and understand about Entity Framework Core code-first with existing database in ASP.NET Core MVC project. Of course, I am not using MVC concepts here as it is basic learning.

I have a database `MyDatabase` with two tables - `Department` and `Employee`.

Hence, I have created this `Department` class in the `Models` folder:

```
namespace CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase.Models
{
    public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is the `Employee` class:

```
namespace CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

Below is the `DbContext` class:

```
namespace CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase.Models
{
    public class EFCFWithExistingDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public EFCFWithExistingDBContext(DbContextOptions<EFCFWithExistingDBContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is how I have added `DbContext` to the services in the `Startup.cs` file:

```
services.AddDbContext<EFCFWithExistingDBContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabaseConnection")));
```

And this is the connection string I have declared in the `appsettings.json` file:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
     "MyDatabaseConnection": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=sa;Password=foobar"
  }
```

This is the code in `HomeController` to test whether records are coming from `Department` and `Employee` table.

```
namespace CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly EFCFWithExistingDBContext _context;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, EFCFWithExistingDBContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
            var employees = _context.Departments.ToList();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have executed below command inside Package Manager console.

```
Add-Migration Initial
```

From the generated `Migrations` folder, I have just commented out all the code inside the `Up` method like this:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    //migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    //    name: "Departments",
    //    columns: table => new
    //    {
    //        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
    //            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
    //        Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
    //        Location = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
    //    },
    //    constraints: table =>
    //    {
    //        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Departments", x => x.Id);
    //    });

    //migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    //    name: "Employees",
    //    columns: table => new
    //    {
    //        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
    //            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
    //        Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
    //        Salary = table.Column<decimal>(nullable: false),
    //        DepartmentId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
    //    },
    //    constraints: table =>
    //    {
    //        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Employees", x => x.Id);
    //    });
}
```

Now, I used `Update-Database` command with a `-v` flag:

```
Update-Database -v
```

This generated logs:

```
Using project 'CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase'.
Using startup project 'CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile F:\Ashok\VS2019\Practice_Web_MVC_WebAPI_NetCore\CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\Ashok\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig F:\Ashok\VS2019\Practice_Web_MVC_WebAPI_NetCore\CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase.runtimeconfig.json C:\Users\Ashok\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\3.1.7\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll database update --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly F:\Ashok\VS2019\Practice_Web_MVC_WebAPI_NetCore\CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase.dll --startup-assembly F:\Ashok\VS2019\Practice_Web_MVC_WebAPI_NetCore\CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase.dll --project-dir F:\Ashok\VS2019\Practice_Web_MVC_WebAPI_NetCore\CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase\ --language C# --working-dir F:\Ashok\VS2019\Practice_Web_MVC_WebAPI_NetCore --root-namespace CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase
Using assembly 'CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase'.
Using startup assembly 'CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase'.
Using application base 'F:\Ashok\VS2019\Practice_Web_MVC_WebAPI_NetCore\CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1'.
Using working directory 'F:\Ashok\VS2019\Practice_Web_MVC_WebAPI_NetCore\CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase'.
Using root namespace 'CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase'.
Using project directory 'F:\Ashok\VS2019\Practice_Web_MVC_WebAPI_NetCore\CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase\'.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.
Found DbContext 'EFCFWithExistingDBContext'.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using context 'EFCFWithExistingDBContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[30000]
      No type was specified for the decimal column 'Salary' on entity type 'Employee'. This will cause values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values using 'HasColumnType()'.
Finding design-time services for provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'.
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase'.
No referenced design-time services were found.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase'...
No design-time services were found.
Done.
```

When verified the generated log, towards the end of the file, the below statement is bothering me. Can it show impact on the result?

```
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase'.
No referenced design-time services were found.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase'...
No design-time services were found.
```

Now, executed the project by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>. But, I'm not getting rows from database table. No errors either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my issue. Resolution is very simple, just need to add `[Table(name)]` attribute to those classes in Models folder like below.

```
namespace CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase.Models
{
    [Table("Department")] //<--Now, I have added this line of code
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    }   
}
namespace CodeFirstWithExistingDatabase.Models
{

    [Table("Employee")] //<--Now, I have added this line of code
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,4)")]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    }   
}
```